# Writing in HTML using Java

Tags: java, html

I have an html file already, and i have a java file that contain methods returning integers.

i want to print those integers in the html, is it possible to transfer the data from java to html and what is the simplest way?

Comment: use a `FileReader / Writer` to read the html file and write the integers to it

Comment: Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can write html Templates and fill them with java.
For example:

```
String html=
"<div>{{key_name}}</div>";

String value=42+"";
String key="key_name";
html=html.replaceAll("{{"+key+"}}",value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write it in JavaScript. Link your html file to a JavaScript document, or write it in  tags. Its not the same language obviously, but basic syntax such as returning numbers is very similar and not only is there less chance of error, but there it is easier to fix. Its hard to say without seeing how much Java code you have written though. If you are interested in web development JavaScript is extremely important to learn and if you know Java it should not be too difficult to pick up the basics. This being said JavaScript is very finicky.